# swift 3 share extension behaves strangely the first time and in debug mode

Tags: swift3, xcode8, ios10, share-extension

I have a very weird behavior with my share extension I try to implement.
My app is supposed to send image selected by user to a server for analysis. The user selects one photo and presses the `post` button to send it.

Here are the strange behaviors I have:

1. The very first time I use the share extension, it does no go beyond the `attachment.loadItem` call. It does not even print `Before error`. Then, if I repeat the same workflow, it works fine.
2. If I use XCode debugger, I never achieve to enter
   `attachment.loadItem` part. Whatever the number of times I use the
   extension. I can repeat the test several times, my image is never
   posted to the server and neither `Before error`, `There is no
   error`, or `There is an error` are printed. Moreover,
   `attachment.loadItem` is called twice.

I have the following code in the `didSelectPost` function

```
override func didSelectPost() {
        self.extensionContext!.completeRequest(returningItems: [], completionHandler: nil)
        // Make sure we have a valid extension item
        if let content = extensionContext!.inputItems[0] as? NSExtensionItem {

            let contentType = kUTTypeImage as String

            // Verify the provider is valid
            if let contents = content.attachments as? [NSItemProvider] {

                // Look for images
                for attachment in contents {
                    print ("There is \(contents.count) attachments")

                    if attachment.hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier(contentType) {
                        print ("I'm in the hasItemConforming part")
                        attachment.loadItem(forTypeIdentifier: contentType, options: nil) { data, error in
                            print ("Before error")
                            if error == nil {
                                print ("There is no error")
                                let url = data as! URL
                                self.sendToServer(localUrl: url)
                            } else {
                                print ("There is an error")
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

If someone could help me with that, I'll be very grateful. 
Thank you very much for reading and helping.

Edit: Working code.

```
@IBAction func didSelectButton(_ sender: Any) {
        // This is called after the user selects Post. Do the upload of contentText and/or NSExtensionContext attachments.

        // Inform the host that we're done, so it un-blocks its UI. Note: Alternatively you could call super's -didSelectPost, which will similarly complete the extension context.


        if let inputItem = extensionContext!.inputItems.first as? NSExtensionItem {
            if let itemProvider = inputItem.attachments?.first as? NSItemProvider {
                if self.isInternetAvailable(){
                    if itemProvider.hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier(kUTTypeImage as String) {

                        progressHUD = MBProgressHUD.showAdded(to: self.view, animated: true)
                        progressHUD.mode = MBProgressHUDMode.determinate
                        progressHUD.detailsLabel.text = message
                        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(cancelButton))
                        progressHUD.addGestureRecognizer(tap)


                        var imageExt = String()
                        let imageName = generateRandomStringWithLength(length: 12)

                        if itemProvider.hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier(kUTTypeJPEG as String) {
                            imageExt = ".jpeg"
                            print ("le type est \(imageExt)")
                        }
                        if itemProvider.hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier(kUTTypePNG as String) {
                            imageExt = ".png"
                            print ("le type est \(imageExt)")
                        }
                        if itemProvider.hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier(kUTTypeGIF as String) {
                            imageExt = ".gif"
                            print ("le type est \(imageExt)")
                        }
                        if itemProvider.hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier(kUTTypeTIFF as String) {
                            imageExt = ".tiff"
                            print ("le type est \(imageExt)")
                        }

                        var myData: Data? = nil

                        itemProvider.loadItem(forTypeIdentifier: kUTTypeImage as String){ [unowned self] (data, error) in
                            //let myImage: UIImage?
                            switch data {
                            case let image as UIImage:
                                //myImage = image
                                myData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)
                                imageExt = ".png"
                            case let data as Data:
                                //myImage = UIImage(data: data)
                                myData = data
                            case let url as URL:
                                //let imageData = NSData(contentsOf: url.absoluteURL)
                                //myImage = UIImage(data: imageData! as Data)
                                //let sourcePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: url.absoluteString, ofType: "gif")
                                //print ("Le source path est \(type(of: sourcePath))")
                                do{
                                    try myData = Data(contentsOf: url)
                                }catch let error{
                                    print ("Error \(error)")
                                }

                            default:
                                //There may be other cases...
                                print("Unexpected data:", type(of: data))
                                //myImage = nil
                            }
                            //imageName is set depending on the extension
                            let myImageName = imageName.appending(imageExt)
                            print ("final name is \(myImageName)")

                            self.sendToServer(imageData: myData!, imageName: myImageName)
                        }


                    } else if itemProvider.hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier("public.movie")  {
                        let pre = NSLocale.preferredLanguages[0]
                        var message = String()
                        if pre.hasPrefix("fr-") {
                            message = "Annuler"
                        }
                        else{
                            message = "Tap to cancel"
                        }
                        progressHUD = MBProgressHUD.showAdded(to: self.view, animated: true)
                        progressHUD.mode = MBProgressHUDMode.determinate
                        progressHUD.detailsLabel.text = message
                        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.cancelButton))
                        progressHUD.addGestureRecognizer(tap)


                        itemProvider.loadItem(forTypeIdentifier: "public.movie", options: nil, completionHandler: { (url, error) in

                            //////TOUT ÇA EST À CORRIGER, ce n'est pas propre ///////////////
                            var urlString = url.debugDescription as! String
                            var urlString2 : String?
                            urlString2 = urlString.replacingOccurrences(of: "Optional(file://", with: "")
                            urlString2 = urlString2?.replacingOccurrences(of: ")", with: "")
                            //////TOUT ÇA EST À CORRIGER ///////////////


                            print("Video Selected")
                            let appGroupDirectory = self.appGroupContainerURL()
                            let frameCount = 64
                            let delayTime  = Float(0.2)
                            let loopCount  = 0    // 0 means loop forever
                            let fnameTmp = self.generateRandomStringWithLength(length: 8)
                            let fname = fnameTmp+".jpg"
                            let fnameGif = appGroupDirectory?.appendingPathComponent(fnameTmp+".gif")


                            Regift.createGIFFromSource(url as! URL, destinationFileURL : fnameGif, frameCount: frameCount, delayTime: delayTime, loopCount: loopCount) { (result) in
                                print("Gif saved to \(result)")
                            }

                            let snapshot = self.videoSnapshot(filePathLocal: urlString2! as NSString)
                            let jpgImageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(snapshot!, 0.4)!
                            let newFname = fnameTmp+".gif"
                            let mimetype = "image/gif"
                            //dataToSend = regift
                            var dataToSend = Data()

                            do {
                                dataToSend = try NSData(contentsOf: fnameGif!) as Data

                            } catch {
                                print(error)
                                return
                            }

                            let fileManager = FileManager.default
                            do {
                                if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: (fnameGif?.path)!) {
                                    try fileManager.removeItem(atPath: (fnameGif?.path)!)
                                }
                            } catch let error as NSError {
                                print(error.debugDescription)
                            }

                            let filePath = appGroupDirectory?.appendingPathComponent(fname)
                            do{
                                try jpgImageData.write(to: (filePath)!)
                            }catch let error{
                                print ("Error \(error)")
                            }


                            self.sendToServer(imageData: dataToSend, imageName: newFname)

                        })
                    }
                }
                else{
                    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                        let noInternetHud = MBProgressHUD.showAdded(to: self.view, animated: true)
                        noInternetHud.mode = MBProgressHUDMode.text
                        noInternetHud.label.text = "No Internet Available"
                        noInternetHud.hide(animated: true, afterDelay: 2)
                    })
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you ever sort this out?

Comment: I don't remember what was the issue but I update my question with a working code.